# Display Partial if user on specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a page with the following URL:
http://www.mywebsite.com/users/profile/edit

How would I display a partial ONLY if the user is on that particular page?

Someone suggested this code, but the syntax confuses me and I was hoping for something more specific.
`<%= render :partial => "foo/bar" if @conditions %>`

Comment: Why not just modify the view for that page?

Comment: the suggested code is fine. What do you mean by `more specific`?

Comment: The suggested code is fine. Whats the confusion?

Comment: I mean I actually don't know how to implement it.  I know that sounds silly, but I kind of need the steps spelled out.  I don't know what @conditions are, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually you put the call to display the partial in the view for that action. If you have a view used by more than one, the standard procedure is as you describe where `@conditions` represents some arbitrary conditions. It could be like this:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'example') if (params[:action] == 'edit') %>
```

Comment: 'params[:controller]' for the controller, '@controller.controller_name' and '@controller.action_name' also work

Comment: Always look at what the `params` are set to in `log/development.log` to know what you have to work with.