# Display a Partial only if user is on a specific page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a main layout page with a menu bar on the left displaying links to other pages. I'm trying to include a partial under that menubar on the left ONLY when the user is on a specific page within that layout.

[Here is another question that is asking for pretty much the same thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070413/display-partial-if-user-on-specific-page)

The problem with that question is the answers are over five years old, and the outdated `<% %>` syntax isn't working in my website.

Is there a way to do the same thing while still using the regular `@Html.Partial` syntax?

Comment: The linked question of for ruby-on-rails, not asp.net-mvc :). Make use of `Sections` - [Layouts and Sections with Razor](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your page layout, where you want to include your side bar:

```
<div id="header">
</div>

@RenderSection("Sidebar", false)

<div id="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

false means it is not a required section, so pages that don't need don't need to include it.

now to display the section, simply add it to the bottom of the page that needs it displayed, other pages within the same layout will not display this section:

```
<h2>This is a page</h2>

@section Sidebar {
   <div id="sidebar">
       your sidebar....
   </div>
}
```

Your full html will display something like this with a sidebar:

```
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
    your sidebar....
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h2>This is a page</h2>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

and other pages will simply be:

```
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h2>This is another page</h2>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```